# Today is a sad day

Tags: no-computers, word-search

Today is a sad day - Today, it was supposed to be *my* big day to shine! But unfortunately that is no longer the case.

I have heard from others here that puzzle-making is a great way to drown out one's sorrows. So here's one for you all to try.

[image: wordsearch]

(Text version)

```
C H O V I I D B A C H C T
R A C H M A N I N O V C R
A N D W E L N I C E H L A
N D E A N I B L S A E I Z
I E B G D S D R I S D C O
P L U N E Z L K A L O A M
O S S E L T O S A H I R C
H A S R S V L V C O M N C
C A Y K S N I V A R T S E
R T Y K O V D V O R A K I
A M Y D H S C H U B E R T
S A D X N E V O H T E E B
```

After all 18 words are found, please tell me **why I am so sad?**

---

(Please do not use any wordsearch solver or any other computer tools)

Comment: Puzzling.SE always yields the weirdest thread titles in the Hot Network Questions list...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The solution reads:

> Covid cancelled classical concert. I am sad.

Solved crossword image:

> [image]

Words found:

> Bach, Beethoven, Brahms, Chopin, Debussy, Dvorak, Handel, Haydn, Lizst, Mendelssohn, Mozart, Rachmaninov, Rossini, Schubert, Stravinsky, Tchaikovsky, Vivaldi, Wagner

> All are surnames of famous classical music composers.

Finally:

> The remaining letters are COVID CANCELLED CLASSICAL CONCERT I AM SAD [X].

Comment: Wow that was fast! Good job

Comment: Is it a sign of hyper-awareness of current events that I instantly saw the first word of the final message before finding *any* of the hidden words?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I did spot that fairly early on too. Once it was time to check for remaining missed words, that made it pretty easy to guess pieces of the phrase and search from extra letters that should be in words.